# Changing the latex path for the conda enviroment to match the system's

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, conda

Sorry for the rookie question, but I have the following issue:

When I'm in a conda environment and I try some `matplotlib` figures with latex fonts, I get errors.

Without going into detail, the command `latex` on base environment (when `which latex` echos this path: `/home/username/scr/miniconda3/bin/latex`) has the following error: `warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf ...`

But, when I use `latex` after `conda deactivate` (where `which latex` matches `/usr/bin/latex`) everything is working correctly.

Is there a way to change conda's/matplotlib's path to latex, so I can work inside conda environment for my latex-including figure scripts which work outside any conda environment using the system's `latex`?

Comment: Is there a good reason why latex is installed in your base env? Would uninstalling it be an option?

Comment: If I uninstall it, then I won't have latex in base enviroment, no?

Comment: It will always call `/usr/bin/latex` then. The environment's path is prepended to PATH so that when you type `latex` while the env is active, your system will first check if there is a `latex` in that env. If not, it will look in the system directories and pick up `/usr/bin/latex`

Comment: So unless you need a different version of `latex` in your base env than in your system, there should be no reason to have it installed there

Comment: @FlyingTeller I tried this. You are actually right! But then, when I try to plot I get his message: `FileNotFoundError: missing font metrics file: cmss17` which is not apparent when I'm plotting on non-anaconda envriment